# Formating fortran code with sed

Tags: sed, fortran

I wrote this `sed` code to format my fortran code:

```
sed -r   's/ +/ /g'   main.f08 |sed -r  's/(\W|,)/ \1/g' |sed -r 's/ +/ /g'
```

But my knowledge in `sed`is limited.

I want to know, is it possible to cleaning the `fortran` code with `sed`. i.e. adding indents and right space between words.

Is there any better way (software) to clean the Fortran codes.

Probably better solution with `perl` or `python`.

For example suppose this code:

```
 program xytab
 implicit none
 !constructs a table of z =x /y for values of x from 1 to 2 and
 !y from 1 to 4 in steps of .5
 real : : x,y,z
 print *, '           x           y           z'
 do x=1,2
 do y=1,4,0.5
 z =x /y
 print *,x,y,z
 end do
 end do
 end program xytab
```

I want to get something like this:

```
program  xytab
    implicit none
    !constructs a table of z=x/y for values of x from 1 to 2 and
    !y from 1 to 4 in  steps of .5
    real :: x, y, z
    print *, '           x           y           z'
    do  x = 1, 2
        do y = 1,4, 0.5
            z = x / y
            print *, x, y, z
        end do
    end  do
end  program xytab
```

[Reference](http://www.fortrantutorial.com/loops/index.php)

Comment: an example anlong with expected output would be better.

Comment: Have you looked at [TIDY6.21](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/ests0643/)?

Comment: Can I use it with the new version of Fortran?

Comment: You should be able to use a single `sed` command.  You can use `-e … -e …` to do two different operations in a single command, and you can do as many repetitions of the `-e …` as you like/need.

Comment: Your first `sed` operation is going to trash the spaces in the string literal.  Avoiding that is going to be hard — very hard.  Keeping track of nesting levels in `sed` is also going to be hard — very hard again.  Golly, it looks funny seeing `do` loops without the label number!  But the last time I used Fortran, Fortran 77 was the latest and greatest; things have changed.

Comment: @John1024 that software is hopelessly obsolete. *TIDY accepts as input ANSI FORTRAN 77 source, some IBM- and CDC-specific statements, and FORTRAN II and FORTRAN IV source statements.* It is 2015. The OP's code Fortran 90 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My earlier comment, converted to an answer so this question can be marked as answered ...

One of the difficult problems with the `sed` approach is going to be ensuring that indentation of `do` and `end do` pairs (and other similar indent-causing pairs) correctly match up. This is something which strict (as in complying closely with the theoretical model of regular expressions familiar from introductory computer science texts) regular-expression tools just can't do.  (For further evidence, proof even, search around on SO for Qs and As relating to bracket-matching in regular expressions.)

Personally I wouldn't use `sed` for this. I'd load the source into a programmer's editor, use that tool's facility for formatting code, then, as they say, *Robert is your mother's brother*. Even if that's all you ever use a programmer's editor for it'll save you a heck of a lot of time trying to get `sed` to do something for which it is ill-suited.  (Of course, that isn't all you should be using a programmer's editor for.)  `sed` matches regular expressions quickly but it is rather limited in its capabilities compared with some other implementations such as any library or tool which implements [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions).

And should you, or anyone else, wonder what a *programmer's editor* is, why, it is a text editor which can correctly and automatically indent source code files.